# How do I use flags included in a DLL?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

The function I am using contains three parameters where one of which requires a flag (fCreationDisposition):

> `function MpqOpenArchiveForUpdate(lpFileName: LPCSTR; fCreationDisposition, dwHashTableSize: DWord): THandle; stdcall; external 'lmpqapi.dll';`

The [documentation](http://sfsrealm.hopto.org/inside_mopaq/chapter4.htm) states that there are five usable flags. However, when I use any of the flags Delphi tells me that it is an "undeclared identifier".

Is there anything extra that I must add in order to be able to access the flags without Delphi telling me that it is an "undeclared identifier"?

Note: Under the `uses` section I have called for the function:

> `function MpqOpenArchiveForUpdate(lpFileName: LPCSTR; fCreationDisposition, dwHashTableSize: DWord): THandle; stdcall; external 'lmpqapi.dll';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define the flags in your code.  In Delphi, you have to define everything from scratch, you cannot utilize any pre-made API header files that belong to the DLL, like you can in C/C++.  So you have to track down the flag numeric values (since the documentation does not provide them) and declare them in your code, eg:

```
// these values are just a guess, you will have
// to download the API and look them up...
const
  MOAU_CREATE_NEW = $1;
  MOAU_CREATE_ALWAYS = $2;
  MOAU_OPEN_EXISTING = $4;
  MOAU_OPEN_ALWAYS = $8;
  MOAU_MAINTAIN_LISTFILE = $10;
```

Comment: I believe I have found the correct values. They take the form of 0x00, 0x08, 0x04 etc. Anyway what does the dollar sign denote in the code above?

Comment: @peter Have you read the Delphi documentation yet? Please take some time to do so. This is very basic. You should know this. $ prefixes hex numbers. Just like 0x in C family. You must read this: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the declaration of the flag values in the C++ header file. And then translate those declarations into your Delphi code. It will look like this:

```
const
  MOAU_CREATE_NEW = ...;
  MOAU_CREATE_ALWAYS = ....;
  etc.
```

I don't have the header file so I cannot fill in the values.